# Google Maps iOS: Move camera to show all markers present inside a cluster

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-ios-utils

When didTap cluster function is called, it zooms the camera to one of the markers present inside the cluster but I want to show all the markers that were in that cluster and focus the camera on those markers.

I was able to achieve this in android. However in iOS the google utils sdk doesn't provide a way to get all the items present in a cluster object.

Here's the android code

```
mClusterManager
            .setOnClusterClickListener(new 
ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<Service_Provider>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClusterClick(final Cluster<Service_Provider> cluster) {
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
        for (ClusterItem item : cluster.getItems()) {
           builder.include(item.getPosition());
          Log.w(TAG, "Clicked Cluster Item name: " + item.getTitle());
         }
        final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

What I have tried in iOS so far

```
func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap cluster: 
GMUCluster) -> Bool {
    print("Did tap cluster")
    let newCamera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: cluster.position,
                                             zoom: mapView.camera.zoom +1)
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.setCamera(newCamera)
    mapView.moveCamera(update)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

```
func showBoundBox( _ list : [CLLocationCoordinate2D]){
    
    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    for location in list {
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(location)
    }
        
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 100)
    map.animate(with: update)
    
}
```